# open my file PDF in PDFAnnotation , swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I want to ask about something very important to me

I made an application containing buttons
These buttons have PDF files

But when I click on the PDF file in the application I have several options `QuickView , Print , Create PDF`

[image: 1]

Such as this picture

But can I when I click on a PDF file that opens automatically in `Create PDF`?

Like what you see in the picture `PDFAnnotation`

[image: 2]

i know how to open PDF file in swift but i want to open it in `Create PDF`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var document: UIDocumentInteractionController = {

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Steve", withExtension: "pdf")

        let vc = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url!)

        vc.delegate = self

        return vc

    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

    }


    @IBAction func doAction1(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        document.presentOptionsMenu(from: view.bounds, in: view, animated: true)
    }


    @IBAction func doAction2(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        document.presentOptionsMenu(from: view.bounds, in: view, animated: true)
    }


    @IBAction func doAction3(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        document.presentOptionsMenu(from: view.bounds, in: view, animated: true)
    }

}



extension ViewController: UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {
    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
        return self
    }

}
```

Comment: You can open in in a webview for example.

Comment: @Sulthan i know how to open PDF file in swift but my question is , how to open the PDF file in Create PDF as the picture

Comment: @Sulthan My topic is not duplicate , i am using Swift not Objectav-c

Comment: @Sulthan he want to open pdf with annotation tool